# Scala newInstance() an inner class nested in a trait

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm writing a script to automatically configure sharding for some specific MongoDB collections when the app is being deployed on a fresh cluster. The application is using the Lift framework and basically every sharded collection is mapped to a MongoRecord class extending a particular "ShardedCollection" trait.  I need to call a particular method on those classes in order to get their collection name.

So the first step is to find in the code those specifics classes and for that I use [ClassUtil](http://software.clapper.org/classutil/) . Then I need a way to instantiate them and for that I thought that java reflection should be able to do it. It's working but only if those classes do not belong to an outer class.

The configuration in this specific edge case is like:

```
class X {
  class Y extends ShardedCollection {

  }
}
```

So after reading some documentation I found that I had to call `YConstructor.newInstance(XObject)`, newInstance taking as a first argument an XObject (as an instance of X) When Y is an inner class of X. My strategy is to recursively instantiate the enclosing classes until I'm getting the one that has the ShardedCollection trait.

The problem arise when X is no more a class but a trait, and then there is no constructor that I can use for it, but I still need to feed an XObject to newInstance .. Tricky :(

---

To be very concise [from the java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-)

> If the constructor's declaring class is an inner class in a non-static context, the first argument to the constructor needs to be the enclosing instance

What do I do when the enclosing "thing" is a trait ? (assuming that I can't modify anything in the code base)

Comment: What's the goal at first?

Comment: I edited the question, hope you will find it more clear.

Comment: I doubt very much the reflection is the better way to achieve that. Using genericity and types should be possible, and less error prone.

Comment: I agree that reflection should be avoided but here I can't find any other way without changing anything in the code base unfortunately.

Comment: If worst comes to worst, you can use the scala compiler API (!), assume that the trait has no abstract members (!!), generate an AST representing a dummy subclass of the trait (!!!), compile that AST at runtime (!!!!), reflectively construct the resultant `Class<?>` (!!!!!), and then use that (!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! × ∞). I won't give details because I don't really know them, and anyway, it's so filthy that there is certainly a better way. Perhaps open another question with details and see if you can't get a second opinion  on the necessity of reflection.

Comment: Yes I had this idea too but I can't assume that the trait or the abstract class has no abstract members and then it become too much complicated . Is there any way to force instantiation of an abstract class/trait through reflection ?  The method that I need to call at the end make no usage of any existing enclosing instances ..

Comment: Add on to the hackage above by also programmatically implementing  abstract members with ???, I guess. But really you should just stop this insanity and a) copy that method into your own code, or b) ask SO and see if there __*really*__ isn't another way. Please, for the sake of sanity.